# Why doesn't the Akka Persisence Query Read Journal retrieve my events?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I have problems understanding Akka Persistence Query, especially the method **eventsByTag** since it doesn't behave like I expect.

In my main class I call a class that starts listening to any events being persisted with a certain tag.

```
class CassandraJournal(implicit val system: ActorSystem) {

 def engageStreaming = {
   val readJournal = PersistenceQuery(system).readJournalFor[CassandraReadJournal](CassandraReadJournal.Identifier)
   implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

   readJournal.eventsByTag("account", Offset.noOffset)
     .runForeach { event => println(event) }
   }
}
```

Whenever I start my server and my event store is empty and I persist my first event (by calling a http service, built in Akka HTTP), the event indeed gets printed. However, when I restart the server and there are already events in the event store, the new persisted events won't get printed.

Is there an explanation for this? I have a hard time figuring out why this is happening.

**EDIT**

The event store I'm using is Cassandra. Here is the PersistentActor (I am not using an Event Adapter to tag the events, just wrap them around a Tagged())

```
class Account(id: UUID) extends PersistentActor {

  override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case createCheckingsAccount: CreateCheckingsAccount =>
      println("Creating checkings account")
  }

  override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case createCheckingsAccount: CreateCheckingsAccount =>
      persist(Tagged(CheckingsAccountCreated(id), Set("account"))) { event =>
        val checkingsAccountCreatedEvent = event.payload.asInstanceOf[CheckingsAccountCreated]
        sender ! CreateCheckingsAccountResponse(checkingsAccountCreatedEvent.id.toString)
      }

  }

  def updateState(evt: Event): Unit = {
  }

  override def persistenceId: String = s"account-$id"
}
```

Comment: Update question with event adapter, persistent actor, and which data store you use for persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `receiveRecover` not doing the necessary state recovery work, persistence wouldn't work properly.  I would suggest putting some basic state recovery logic in `receiveRecover` and have your `updateState` method cover also tagged event cases.

I used `eventsByTag` in an app with state recovery logic similar to the following and it worked fine on both fresh start and recovery.

```
def updateState(e: Any): Unit = e match {
  case evt: Event =>
    state = state.updated(evt)
  case Tagged(evt: Event, _) =>
    state = state.updated(evt)
}

...

override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
  case evt: Event => updateState(evt)
  case taggedEvt: Tagged => updateState(taggedEvt)
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working by indeed setting up some proper recovery work. I wasn't aware of the fact that recovery would run on a fresh start. Thanks for your help!