# EventsByTag support in EventStore

Tags: akka-persistence, eventstoredb

Am using [EventStore](http://eventstore.org) as the `ReadJournal` and `akka-persistence` API , to build a persistent view.

The issue am facing is that i do not see the tags in the EventStore GUI after the event is persisted. Therefore, am not sure if the correct tagged event is getting persisted in the eventstore or not.

Going by http://pkaczor.blogspot.in/2015/12/akka-ddd-integrating-eventstore.html and a small test, i see that i am not able to read events persisted by tags in the eventstore through `currentEventsByTag` akka persistence API.

My write event adapter is mentioned below.

```
public class ViewEventAdapter implements WriteEventAdapter {
  @Override
  public String manifest(Object event) {
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public Object toJournal(Object event) {
    if (event instanceof DomainEvent) {
      DomainEvent domainEvent = (DomainEvent) event;
      return tagged(domainEvent , "ViewRelated");
    }
    return event;
  }

  private Tagged tagged(Object event, String tag) {
    Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();
    tags.add(tag);
    return new Tagged(event, tags);
  }
}
```

Following is the configuration.

```
akka.persistence {
    journal {
        plugin = "eventstore.persistence.journal"
        event-adapters {
            tagger = "com.wt.domain.write.events.ViewEventAdapter"
        }

        event-adapter-bindings {
            "com.wt.domain.write.events.DomainEvent" = tagger
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the relevant piece of code where i am persisting the eventByTag.

```
private void handle(DomainEvent event) {
       ViewEventAdapter viewAdapter = new ViewEventAdapter();
        persist(viewAdapter.toJournal(event), evt -> {
          domainObject.update(evt);
          sender().tell("Done"), self());
        });
      } 
  }
```

Any help in this matter is much appreciated.

There is another question on the similar lines here: [Why doesn't the Akka Persisence Query Read Journal retrieve my events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171143/why-doesnt-the-akka-persisence-query-read-journal-retrieve-my-events/47286703#47286703)

Comment: Are they in the metadata?